# How can I add a case, when I uploads a picture to a folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement

I want to make an image gallery where I can upload pictures to a folder, and see them in my gallery. Currently I'm using a switch statement to change the images, but I don't got any idea on how to add uploaded images to the gallery (add a new case to the switch statement, with my image path)

### ImageChanger

```
private void ChangeImage(int num)
    {
        switch (num)
        {
            case 1:
                    Images.Image = Properties.Resources.wp;
                    imageTxt.Text = "Nice mountain";
                break;
            
            case 2:
                    Images.Image = Properties.Resources.wp1;
                    imageTxt.Text = "Nice mountain";
                break;
            
            case 3:
                    Images.Image = Properties.Resources.wp2;
                    imageTxt.Text = "Nice";
                break;
            
            case 4:
                    Images.Image = Properties.Resources.wp3;
                    imageTxt.Text = "Cool";
                break;
            
            case 5:
                    Images.Image = Properties.Resources.wp4;
                    imageTxt.Text = "Damn";
                break;

            case 6:
                    Images.Image = Properties.Resources.wp5;
                    imageTxt.Text = "Okay okay";
                break;

            case 7:
                    Images.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\....\Resources\tree.jpg");
                    imageTxt.Text = "Okay okay";
                break;
        }
    }
```

### SAVE N UPLOAD IMAGES

```
    private void ImageUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png;)| *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png;";
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ImgDirectory.Text = open.FileName;
            picPreview.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        }
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.Copy(ImgDirectory.Text, Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\....\Resources\", Path.GetFileName(ImgDirectory.Text)));
        Update();
    }
```

Comment: Note that the `[visual-studio]` tag is reserved for questions about Visual Studio. I've removed it for you.

Comment: switch/case is not the right tool for this situation. You may want to consider something like Dictionary or even a List may be enough ...

Comment: The problem you have is that case is compile-time. You need a flexible solution, which means using a memory structure. If you're just calling `ChangeImage` with increasing values of `num` (i.e. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, etc.) then perhaps a `Queue<something>` would be a good solution as you can dequeue the next item, though you would probably need to create a type that contains both the image source location, and the string to display.

Comment: Hey @John, appreciate your time and answer, I'll take a look at it! Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My solution

Hey, I figured it out!

I just created an array with the images.
Like so: `string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\....\Resources");`

And added a counter: `private int counter = 0;`

On my "Next pic and previous pic button" I just did like so:

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        if (images.Length == 0) return;

        if (counter > imgAmount + -1) counter = 0;
        var image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);
        Images.Image = image;

        CurrentImg.Text = counter+1 + "/" + imgAmount.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should better use another method. Like using **Collections**

```
public class UploadedImage
{
  public UploadImage(string inputPath, string inputName){
    imagePath = inputPath;
    imageName = inputName
  }
  string imagePath { get; set; }
  string imageName { get; set; }
}
```

Declare it

```
public List<UploadedImage> yourImages ;
```

Assign your available images to yourImages

```
yourImages = new List<UploadedImage>();
yourImages.Add(new UploadImage("wp", "Nice mountain"));
yourImages.Add(new UploadImage("wp1", "Nice mountain"));
/* ... */
```

In your **Upload** function, add recently uploaded image into **yourImages**

```
yourImages.Add(new UploadImage(Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\....\Resources\", Path.GetFileName(ImgDirectory.Text)), ImageName);
```

Comment: Hey @tinypomelo, I'm kindda new to this, and tried pasting it into my code, but it seems like I get a lot of errors. Would you be so kind to write it all out in one block of code, so I can get a better understanding of it!

Comment: Am I supposed to do it this way? 
https://imgur.com/a/CbQ1P23

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QridRGf Here you are. "ImageName" is a string you want to name your image (you can create a textbox to assign value to it e.g: ImageName = Textbox1.Text;)

Comment: Hey @tinypomelo, I figured it out! Check out my solution below!